# Deleting a cookie from a cookie jar using the node request module

Tags: node.js

So I'm using the node request module, and I'm creating a cookie jar in my code like this:

```
currentCookieJar = request.jar();
```

And I'm adding a bunch of cookies to it while my server is running, and I want a way to remove/replace a cookie when I believe it is expired. But I looked through the documentation for npm request, and there doesn't seem to be anyway to remove a cookie from the jar. How do I delete/overwrite a cookie that i don't want anymore without deleting all the cookies in the jar?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies